# How to fix identify why react receives a 200 empty response from Azure functions, where Azure function sends a 200 response with body?

Tags: react-redux, azure-functions

I have configured an Azure Functions app with some functions. When I hit one of the functions from the react app, it is getting a 200 empty response. But when I check the response sent, it has body with the content. What would be the reason for this issue?

This is occurring randomly for some functions.

Comment: Can you post the response code ?